# where are MacPorts binary files?

Tags: macos, ant, macports

I am trying to use the ant `rpm` task to build a Linux installer on Mac OSX.

I installed MacPorts and compiled rpm which now works from the command line.

However, I would like it to work with ant (from inside Eclipse), but ant cannot find any `rpm` executable. In fact, `whereis rpm` does not find it either. Confused..

I also tried to create a separate rpm binary installer using macports (`sudo port pkg rpm`), but after installing that one nothing changed.

Where is the rpm binary?

Comment: Typically in `/opt/local/bin`.

Comment: great, works. not sure why `whereis` is not picking it up there though.. Add it as answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacPorts binaries can be found in `/opt/local/bin`.

According to the man page, `whereis` only searches directories contained in the `user.cs_path` sysctl variable (at least on OS X). This value defaults to `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` on my machine.